# How Do I Make My GUI Console Execute more than once? E.G. Reloop Commands

Tags: java, swing, loops, runtime.exec

I've Been Working on a command executer via Java. I wanted to know if I could loop this more than once, and if so, how? Example In Sudo Code in steps:

1. Build Swing Components
2. Execute command from Input dialog
3. print syncpipe on components (Command's StdOut)
4. Prompt to Run another command
5. if true then Re Execute Another Command from Input dialog aka return to step 2 and keep the text on my text area.

Sorry for my poor clarity.

Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Dos implements Runnable
{
 private PipedOutputStream pipeout;
 private PipedOutputStream pipeerr;

 String command = "cmd /K ";


 public Dos ( String[] cmd )

 {

  pipeout = null;
  pipeerr = null;
 }

 @Override
 public void run ()
 {
  exec ();
 }

 public void exec ()
 {

      // Class to redirect the process input stream to a piped output stream

      class OutputMonitor implements Runnable
      {
           InputStream is;
           PipedOutputStream pout;

           public OutputMonitor ( InputStream i, PipedOutputStream p )
           {
            is = i;
            pout = p;
           }
           public void run ()
           {
                try
                {
                     int inputChar;

                     for ( ;; )
                     {
                        inputChar = is.read();
                        if ( inputChar == -1 )
                        { break; }

                        if ( pout == null )
                        {
                             System.out.write ( inputChar );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             pout.write ( inputChar );

                        }
                   }
                   if ( pout != null )
                   {
                        pout.flush ();
                        pout.close ();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        System.out.flush();
                   }
                }
                catch ( Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace (); }
           }
        }

      try
      {
           Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime ();
           JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "(uses quotes for system Commands eg: \"java -jar BuildTools.jar --Latest \" )");
           String cmdargs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in Command:", "");
           Process p = r.exec (command + cmdargs);

           OutputMonitor out = new OutputMonitor ( p.getInputStream (), pipeout );
           OutputMonitor err = new OutputMonitor ( p.getErrorStream (), pipeerr );

           Thread t1 = new Thread ( out  );
           Thread t2 = new Thread ( err );

           t1.start ();
           t2.start ();

      }
      catch ( Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace (); }

 }

 public PipedInputStream getInputStream () throws IOException
 {
      pipeout = new PipedOutputStream ();
      return new PipedInputStream ( pipeout );
 }

 public PipedInputStream getErrorStream () throws IOException
 {
      pipeerr = new PipedOutputStream ();
      return new PipedInputStream ( pipeerr );
 }

 public void execInThread ()
 {
      Thread t = new Thread ( this );
      t.start ();
 }

 public static JPanel getContentPane ( JTextArea ta )
 {

      JPanel p = new JPanel ( new BorderLayout () );
      JPanel bottom = new JPanel ( new FlowLayout () );
      JButton button = new JButton ( " Exit " );
      button.addActionListener ( new ActionListener ( )
                          {
                               public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e )
                               {
                                    System.exit ( 0 );
                               }
                          }
                     );


      bottom.add ( button );

      p.add ( new JScrollPane ( ta ), BorderLayout.CENTER );
      p.add ( bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
      p.setPreferredSize ( new Dimension ( 640,480 ) );
      return p;
}











 public static void main ( String[] arg )
 {





      class GuiUpdate implements Runnable
      {



           private PipedInputStream pin;
           private PipedInputStream perr;
           private JTextArea outputArea;


            GuiUpdate ( JTextArea textArea, PipedInputStream in )
           {
             pin = in;
             outputArea = textArea;
           }

           @Override
          public void run ()
           {
                // Class to run on the event dispatch thread to update the GUI


                class UpdateSwing implements Runnable
                {
                     String update;
                     JTextArea swingTextArea;

                     public UpdateSwing ( JTextArea a, String s )
                     {
                          update = s;
                          swingTextArea = a;
                     }
                     public void run ()
                     {
                          outputArea.append ( update + "\n" );
                     }
                }

                try
                {
                     // Read file before displaying
                     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( pin ) );
                     String line;

                     for ( ;; )
                     {
                          line = r.readLine ();
                          if ( line == null ) { break; }

                          SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new UpdateSwing ( outputArea, line ) );

                          Thread.yield ();
                     }
                }
                catch ( Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace (); }
           }
      }

      // Create and invoke GUI

      JFrame f = new JFrame ( "Minecraft GUI" );
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.ICONIFIED );
      JTextArea textOutput = new JTextArea (); 
      textOutput.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      textOutput.setForeground(Color.red); 
      f.getContentPane().add ( getContentPane ( textOutput ) );
      JButton b = new JButton("Do Command");
      f.pack();
      f.show ();

      try
      {
           // Create command and setup the pipes

           Dos d = new Dos ( arg );

           PipedInputStream stdout_pipe = d.getInputStream ();
           PipedInputStream stderr_pipe = d.getErrorStream ();
           d.execInThread ( );

          // Results

           Thread t1 = new Thread ( new GuiUpdate ( textOutput, stdout_pipe ) );
           Thread t2 = new Thread ( new GuiUpdate ( textOutput, stderr_pipe ) );

           t1.start ();
           t2.start ();


      }
      catch ( Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace (); }





    }


}
```

Comment: *"I wanted to know if I could loop this more then once and how"* - Yes

Comment: Any Idea On How To Loop This